# Unable to Merge 2 lists and form a master list with two years marks c# linq

Tags: c#, list

I have a list with list1

```
CurrentYearDate    Marks1   LastYearDate    Marks2         
09/01/2012         200       
09/02/2012         10        
09/03/2012         30
09/04/2012         40
```

I have a list with list2

```
CurrentYearDate    Marks1   LastYearDate    Marks2         
                            9/01/2011         10
                            09/02/2011        10
                            09/03/2011        30
                            09/04/2011        40
```

I need to merge the two lists together List master 
I have a list with list1

```
CurrentYearDate    Marks1   LastYearDate    Marks2         
09/01/2012         200      9/01/2011         10
09/02/2012         10       09/02/2011        10
09/03/2012         30       09/03/2011        30
09/04/2012         40       09/04/2011        40
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the indexes line up, as in your example, so that the first item in each list correspond to each other then you can just use `Zip`:

```
var mergedLists = list1.Zip(list2, (a,b)=> new YourClassName()
    {
        CurrentYearDate = a.CurrentYearDate,
        Marks1 = a.Marks1,
        LastYearDate = b.LastYearDate,
        Marks2 = b.Mark2,
    });
```

If the indexes don't correspond then you'll need to use `Join`:

```
var joinedLists = list1.Join(list2, curr => curr.CurrentYearDate, last => last.LastYearDate.AddYears(1), (a,b)=> new YourClassName()
    {
        CurrentYearDate = a.CurrentYearDate,
        Marks1 = a.Marks1,
        LastYearDate = b.LastYearDate,
        Marks2 = b.Mark2,
    });
```